# Search - get tasks where Start date equals to Due date

Tags: search, search-results, search-query

Is it possible to build a search query, where I could fetch all tasks where start date equals to due date?

Something like:
`TaskDueDateOWSDATE=TaskStartDateOWSDATE` assuming I mapped start date to managed property?

Other option would be to introduce calculated column, where when dates are equal, the result would be 0. But If that could be achieved without custom column, that would be the best.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map these columns to DateTime type managed properties like Date00 and Date01 (with refinable, sortable etc properties). Only DateTime can be compared with query (>,<,=, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Search Query to get data. Only thing you need to make sure is the data won't be real time.

1. StartDate managed property is already available out of the box.
2. Create a managed property to map crawled property ows_DueDate.
3. Create a new result source based on the logic "DueDate=StartDate"
4. For displaying result you can use result webpart

Detailed description is available [here](http://www.shillier.com/archive/2013/02/14/create-a-search-based-task-management-solution-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

If you are using REST API then use following query to get the data

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='search term'&sourceid='B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31' (this example is to search the 'People' result source, change it to the new result source you created in step 3)
```